# Repeated writes to windows host file result in sporadic "Permission denied" errors in Ruby File.open

Tags: ruby

OS: Win10 x64

Ruby version: 1.9.3

I'm trying to write up to 7 entries into the windows hosts file, one line at a time, using the following:

```
File.open(HOSTS_FILE_PATH, 'w') do |file|
  file.write(clean_content.join(''))
end
```

Occasionally, all 7 lines are written. More frequently, however, a varying number of lines are written before it fails with this message:

```
ERROR: Permission denied - C:\WINDOWS/System32/drivers/etc/hosts
Stack trace:
C:/dev/git/p/build/common.library/website_utility.rb:293:in `read'
C:/dev/git/p/build/common.library/website_utility.rb:293:in `add_hosts_entry'
build.rb:46:in `add_host_entries'
build.rb:158:in `block in <main>'
C:/dev/git/p/build/common.library/build_process.rb:16:in `start'
build.rb:155:in `<main>'
```

If I add `sleep 0.1` after the `end` line of the block, all 7 lines are always written, which leads me to suspect that perhaps the file has not been closed in time for the next attempt to open it to succeed. Am I correct in my assumption? Is there a better way to fix it than the sleep? Or is it likely to be due to something else entirely?

Comment: May be each time you update that file, Windows opens it to process the data or something, and that's where you're getting the error. Have you tried writing all the lines in a single operation? Or just don't close the file until you finish with it.

Comment: That refactoring is under consideration. This has been working for the last few years, it's just stopped now and I'm trying to figure out why.